# Preventing text or object from reflecting in scene (blend file included)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, text-object, reflection

I have an object / text that reflects in a scene is there a way to have the text / object be excluded from creating reflections onto other objects?

I would like the text to look "normal" and not have it create reflections in the scene.

See attach image and blend file below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you are doing animation, otherwise I would suggest inserting the text in GIMP or something after rendering.

With cycles and using Blender 2.82a, you can select the text and in the "**Object Properties**" panel under *Visibility* and under *Ray Visibility* un-check everything except *Camera*. This excludes your text from any reflection calculations.

[image]

Or you could put the text and a copy of the camera into a different scene and overlay it in the compositor (using an "alpha over"-node for example).

Comment: Thanks!.........